# How to assign a variable using onclick of html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a code where the onclick of html should cause a javascript variable to be assigned a value which causes a function to trigger.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function set_str(numb)
 {
   if(numb == 1)
   var str_in_func = 'a.tab_1';
   else if(numb == 2)
      var str_in_func = 'a.tab_2';
   return str_in_func;
}
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
str = set_str(num);

// When a link is clicked
$(str).click(function () {


// switch all tabs off
$(".active").removeClass("active");

// switch this tab on
$(this).addClass("active");

// slide all content up
$(".content").slideUp();

// slide this content up
var content_show = $(this).attr("title");
$("#"+content_show).slideDown();

});

});
</script>
```

I want the javascript variable str to have a value of 'a.tab_1' when the link below is clicked

```
<a href="#" title="content_1" onclick="var num = 1; return false;" class="tab_1 active" id="ma_link">Topics</a>
```

This doesn't seem to work though. The above jQuery function doesn't run at all.

Answer (score 4):

There is a much easier approach to this that doesn't require all the mucking about with HTML attributes:

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="tab">tab 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="tab">tab 2</a>
</nav>
<div id="content">
    <section>Content 1</section>
    <section>Content 2</section>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab').on('click', function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $('#content section')
            .slideUp()
            .eq($(this).index()).slideDown()
        ;
    });
});
```

[See demonstration here.](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/tKBeE/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" title="content_1" onclick="var num = 1; return false;" class="tab_1 active" id="ma_link">Topics</a>
```

The problem is the `var` before your variable's name. Remove it and you will be fine. `var` tells javascript that you are declaring a variable for the local scope, not the context of the window, making it unavailable outside of the current context.

You want:

```
<a href="#" title="content_1" onclick="num = 1; return false;" class="tab_1 active" id="ma_link">Topics</a>
```

Comment: Could also use `window.var` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963294/5623661).