# Declare a variable inside onclick?

Tags: javascript

How can I declare a var in JavaScript when someone clicks something and then a variable is declared, depending on what a function will return, which would be either a true or false value.

something like

```
onclick="var varable = somefunction(); "
```

I will then be compare the variable inside the onclick to then execute a function. So if that variable was true a function is executed, if it was false it will return.

How can both of these things be done in js?

Comment: You want to execute one function to return a value, and then, based on that value, you will (or will not) call another function?

Comment: Echoing Sergio, why not just set the variable inside 'somefunction' and then call your other functions also inside 'somefunction'?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that by using `var`, that variable is locally scoped to that click handler and not to the global object, which is `window`.  The easiest fix would be to directly set the value of the variable as a property on `window`:

```
onclick="window.varable = somefunction();"
```

Then you can access `varable` *(sic)* from other parts of the code.

That said, it's generally a bad idea to put application logic directly in onclick attributes.

Comment: Could also use `varable` (the desired variable) only, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8772502/5623661).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve your question is via ternary operator `?`:

```
onclick="myTestFunction() ? onTrueFunction() : onFalseFunction();"
```

So in the end you don't need to declare anything.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the variable in the global scope of your javascript and you assign to it in the click handler:

```
var myVariable;

<a href="xxx" onclick="myVariable = somefunction();">
```

Or, you create another function for the click handler that does the work for you:

```
function dispatchFunction() {
    if (myVariable) {
        someFunction1();
    } else {
        someFunction2();
    }
}


<a href="xxx" onclick="dispatchfunction();">
```

Or, depending upon what you want:

```
function dispatchFunction() {
    if (someFunction0()) {
        someFunction1();
    } else {
        someFunction2();
    }
}
```

The point is that it's usually best to just call a function from the click handler and have that function do whatever work you need done rather than putting multiple statements inline into the click handler HTML.